# Laravel DB facade select dynamicaly

Tags: database, laravel, join, select, laravel-facade

i am trying to make an dynamical select with db facade in Laravel.

```
$EntrepriseSurBAseDuNace = DB::table ('enterpriseAddress')
            ->join('enterpriseEnterprise', 'enterpriseEnterprise.EnterpriseNumber', '=', 'enterpriseAddress.EntityNumber','LEFT OUTER')
            ->select('EntityNumber')
            ->where([
                ['Zipcode','=',$CodePostal],
                ['enterpriseEnterprise.StartDate    ','=',$DateCreation],

            ])
            ->get();
```

And i would like to add join if arrays/Vars aren't empty, something like this :

```
if(isset($Var){
->join ...... 
}
```

or

```
if(isset($Array){
->join ...... 
}
```

but i can't do this in the request. 
Thak's for help and sorry for my english.

Thanks to David  :

```
    $queryTest = DB::table ('enterpriseAddress');
    if (isset($RechercheRequete['CodePostal']))
    {
        $CodePostal = $RechercheRequete['CodePostal'];

        $queryTest->where('enterpriseAddress.Zipcode','=', $CodePostal);

    }



    $result = $queryTest->select('EntityNumber') ->get(); dd($result); 
    exit();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but I can't do this in the request?" What is the specific problem you have?

Comment: oh sorry @MichaelKunst i didn t see it's ok now , i didn't know how i can do if condition in my query ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = DB::table ('enterpriseAddress');

if (your-condition) {
   $query->join(...
} elseif ('other condition') {
   $query->join(...
}
$query->select('EntityNumber')
    ->where([
         ['Zipcode','=',$CodePostal],
         ['enterpriseEnterprise.StartDate    ','=',$DateCreation],
     ])->get();
```

Comment: what is results

Comment: in progress, i ll tell you ;)

Comment: it's working ,  I just do it to all the request that's why it takes so long. Thank's for your help.

Comment: Not really in fact, i didn't see that there is no result.

Comment: what is happen?

Comment: i am maybe an idiot cause i need to do the query and not just print it as a result right or the "->get()" execute the request ?

Comment: it's the way i need to go my problem is in my side i think ;) so your answer is right .

Comment: Also all time you can use dd($query->toSql()) to see your current query

Comment: i check the request and it looks ok but it didn't return me the result. That's my query :  "select `EnterpriseNumber` from `enterpriseEnterprise` inner join `enterpriseDenomination` on `enterpriseDenomination`.`EntityNumber` = `enterpriseEnterprise`.`EnterpriseNumber` inner join `enterpriseAddress` on `enterpriseAddress`.`EntityNumber` = `enterpriseEnterprise`.`EnterpriseNumber` where `enterpriseDenomination`.`Language` = ? and `enterpriseEnterprise`.`TypeOfEnterprise` = ? and `enterpriseAddress`.`Zipcode` = ? ◀"  and i receive a full page with everything Laravel can write but not my result ^^

Comment: I am sorry but i cannot discribe this  better for the moment ^^.

Comment: All time nested query is not better solution. you must be avoid to use nested query. If it is possible

Comment: Sorry David but it looks like not working :/ i edited my post.

Comment: $result = $queryTest->select('EntityNumber')
        ->get();

   dd($result);
    exit();

Comment: hope i make u laugh a bit :D , sorry for my noobie skill thanks for your patience

Comment: David sorry but i wanna do nested query instead of a query of each table, cause the informations for where clauses are all on a different table. Is it better to do a request to db for each where clause ?( i just saw ur comment about that)We discuss a bit about that with a colleague and he tells me to decrease the number of request with join.